# Visual Studio Post-Build xcopy dont work: error MSB3073: :"VCEnd" exited with code 4

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xcopy, post-build-event

I have following post build command:

```
XCOPY "$(SolutionDir)*" "D:\VS\Win1\*" /EXCLUDE:"E:\exclude.txt" /Y /E /D
```

When **building** I get these message:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Win1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  Can't read file: "E:\exclude.txt"
1>  
1>  0 File(s) copied
1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5):
    error MSB3073: The command "XCOPY "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Win1\*" 
    "D:\VS\Win1\*" /EXCLUDE:"E:\exclude.txt" /Y /E /D
1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(113,5):
     error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 4.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**E:\exclude.txt** file content:

```
.sdf

\Debug\

\ipch\

\Trash\
```

I don't know why I get this error. VS say ***Can't read file: "E:\exclude.txt"*** but I check that file exist. I also read other posts on SO but don't see any have same problem. Do you know how to fix it?

**EDIT:**

**xcopy** was successfully copy files, thank to @RustyX's answer. But it still gave error code 1:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Win1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  tkk.cpp
1>  Win1.vcxproj -> D:\T\Win1\Win1.exe
1>  C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Win1\Source\tkk.h
1>  1 File(s) copied
1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(112,5):
    error MSB3073: The command "XCOPY "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Win1\*"
    "D:\VS\Win1\*" /EXCLUDE:E:\exclude.txt /Y /E /D
1>C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(112,5): 
    error MSB3073: echo f | XCOPY "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Win1\Debug\Win1.pch" 
    "D:\VS\Win1\Debug\Win1.pch" /Y /E /F /D" exited with code 1.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

When I run this command in `cmd` window, it says **0 file copied**:

```
XCOPY "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Win1\*"
    "D:\VS\Win1\*" /EXCLUDE:E:\exclude.txt /Y /E /D
```

and:

```
echo f | XCOPY "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Win1\Debug\Win1.pch" 
    "D:\VS\Win1\Debug\Win1.pch" /Y /E /F /D
```

What is the error?

Comment: Look in the Output window for the error message produced by XCopy.

Comment: @HansPassant `xcopy` was successfully copy files, but it still gave error code 1, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You XCOPY command is invalid. If you run it in a command prompt, you'll see that it doesn't work:

```
> XCOPY "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Win1\*" "D:\VS\Win1\*" /EXCLUDE:"E:\exclude.txt" /Y /E /D
Can't read file: "E:\exclude.txt"
```

Try removing the quotes after `/EXCLUDE:`

```
XCOPY "$(SolutionDir)*" "D:\VS\Win1\*" /EXCLUDE:E:\exclude.txt /Y /E /D
```

Comment: Your command gave this error: `VCEnd exited with code 1`, although project was built and files were copied successfully. Do you know why?

Comment: When run `XCOPY "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Win1\*" "D:\VS\Win1\*" /EXCLUDE:"E:\exclude.txt" /Y /E /D` it success, but when run `XCOPY "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Win1\*" "D:\VS\Win1\*" /EXCLUDE:"E:\exclude.txt" /Y /E /D :VCEnd` it fails. I don't know why VS add **:VCEnd** to my command